# Pusher not recognizing Auth data

Tags: json, django, authentication, pusher

I am trying to generate a Pusher authentication string. https://pusher.com/docs/auth_signatures. In my Django view, The response is a JSON string with an auth property just as it asked for.

```
{u'auth': u'1019dcd6d219db50d37e:926260b960edf94509e0fd86547ec756cc4a1006baef4e0b3f8ec35c1e7b8c05'}
```

but I am getting this error.

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth info required to subscribe to private-account-313"}}}
```

Is the JSON formatted incorrectly, or does the issues lie somewhere else ? couldn't find anything on it on Pusher's website.

```
def pusher_auth(request):
    # """ -Pusher private channel authentication
    # Docs: https//pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users
    # """

if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user

    socket_id = request.POST['socket_id']
    channel = request.POST['channel_name']

    if not (socket_id or channel or user):
        raise Exception("Permission denied.")

    fragments = channel.split('-')
    resource = fragments[1]
    resource_id = int(fragments[2])

    account = Account.objects.get(email=user.email)

    pusher_client = Pusher(app_id='199731', key='1019dcd6d219db50d37e', secret='9550fb09aacce399eeb6',
                           cluster='ap1', ssl=True)
    auth = pusher_client.authenticate(channel, socket_id)

    try:
        if resource == 'account' and (account.id == resource_id):
            print(auth)
            context = auth
            return composeJsonResponse(200, "", context)
        else:
            return {'nope'}
    except:
        raise Exception("Permission denied.")
```

The angular code where channel is being subscribed to

```
/**
 * pusher-js wrapper as a factory.
 * Docs: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js
 */
(function () {
    'use strict';

$pusher.$inject = ["Config"];
angular
    .module('app.common')
    .factory('$pusher', $pusher);

/** ngInject */
function $pusher(Config) {
    var self = this;
    self.client = new Pusher(Config.pusher.key, Config.pusher.options || {});

    return {
        client: self.client
    };
}

})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.core')
    .constant('Config', getConfig());

function getConfig() {

    return {
        api_path: '',

        pusher: {
            // TODO: add environment-based configs values.
            key: '1019dcd6d219db50d37e',
            options: {
                encrypted: true
            }
        }
    };
}

})();

    /**
    * Subscribes to user's Pusher channel and binds callback events.
    */
    function bindPusher() {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        var channelName = 'private-account-' + Session.account.id;
        var channel = $pusher.client.subscribe(channelName);

        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function (data) {
            $log.debug('Pusher subscribed: ' + channel.name);
            PushListener.bindAndListen(channel);
            defer.resolve(data);
        });
        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function (status) {
            if (status === 403) {
                var msg = 'Pusher channel not authorized.';
                $log.warn(msg);
                defer.reject(msg);
            }
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the code you're using on the Django server? We have a demo pusher django integration that might be of use: https://github.com/pusher-community/gs-pusher-django

Comment: I could of sworn i replied to you, apologies for the late reply. i attached the code I'm sharing on the Django server. I can't find anything online about this issue, I'm losing my mind lol.